# setState of an empty array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

I'm working on a code where I have an empty array which has to be filled after a certain request returns.

I tried to `setState` of the array like that:

```
const [recentTransactionContacts,setRecentTransactionContacts] = useState<object[]>([])
///// more code

Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
       if(err) throw err
                    
       if(contacts.length > 0)
           setRecentTransactionContacts(prevState => ({...prevState.recentTransactionContacts, ...contacts}));
       else 
           ToastAndroid.show(`There no contacts on your phone. Can't transfer`, ToastAndroid.SHORT) 
})
```

Now, I don't see any change in the array of contacts after trying to do `setState` that way.
The only way, that I could update the state was like that:

```
setRecentTransactionContacts(contacts)
```

However, I don't think that the latter is the correct way.

What is the correct way to update the state of an array?

Comment: how about ```setRecentTransactionContacts([... recentTransactionContacts ,...contacts])``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be served your case, the `recentTransactionContacts` is not changed after this line runs so you do not need to access to prevState to do what you want.

```
setRecentTransactionContacts([...recentTransactionContacts, ...contacts]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `prevState` or [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) is required in cases where the current state might be changed or stale, which doesn't seem to be the case here. Infact it could be the prevState itself causing issues, as the prevState value could be `undefined` at run.

As stated, replace your method to
`setRecentTransactionContacts([...recentTransactionContacts, ...contacts]);`
which will take in the current state value and append the contacts to the state.